# What do I do when nothing happens when I open the system properties in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, properties

I recently reinstall windows 7 but found out that I cannot open the Windows 7 'system properties'.

[image]

Every time I click on "System", nothing happens. I've also tried clicking both "My Computer>Properties" and "Control Panel>System"

However, I can open the XP-style 'System Properties' when I run `control sysdm.cpl`:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by Malware, I would first scan the system.

Follow the order given below to disinfect your PC

1.) On a PC that is Not infected, Make a boot AV disc then boot from the disc on the Infected PC and scan the hard drive, remove any infections it finds, I prefer the Kaspersky disc myself. The New 2010 Kaspersky disc can update the AV dat files if you are connected to the internet at the time of scan and is suggested to update before the scan.

http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/

2.) Then:
Install free MBAM, run the program and go to the Update tab and update it, then go to the Scanner Tab and do a quick scan, select and remove anything it finds.

http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html

3.) When MBAM is done install SAS free version, run a quick scan, remove what it automatically selects.
http://www.superantispyware.com/download.html

These last 2 are not AV softwares like Norton, they are on demand scanners that only scan for nasties when you run the program and will not interfere with your installed AV, these can be run once a day or week to ensure you are not infected. Be sure you update them before each daily-weekly scan.

.

Once the system is cleaned or verified to be clean, run a SFC

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833